# JavaFX Canvas - Expand in a Negative Direction

Tags: canvas, javafx

I am writing a program that involves reading data from a USB device and plotting it on a line graph (canvas). The canvas is placed within a ScrollPane, so when the line reaches the end of the canvas the canvas' size is increased and the ScrollPane automatically scrolls to the right. I want to implement the same functionality in the vertical direction, but `setHeight(double h)` only expands the canvas downward, so this doesn't work for when the line reaches the top of the canvas.

Since the canvas cannot be expanded upward (because that would mean negative area), I was hoping there would be a way to shift all of the previously drawn line downward to make room above it after expanding the canvas downward.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: [tag:jfreechart] renders to a `Canvas` in JavaFX; it supports zoom and pan; more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very bad way to create a line graph on Canvas. Eventually the canvas will reach a maximum size and will start throwing errors when you try to expand it beyond its limit. After letting the graph run for a few minutes this is exactly what happened. A better approach would be to store the USB data somehow and constantly repaint the canvas with the last X number of USB data points to keep the graph "moving".

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any code, so Im assuming a few things. One being that you dont 'save' the drawn content by calling `GraphicsContent#save`. Otherwise you won't be able to accomplish this properly.

Anyways, here is how you might accomplish a transformation (not tested yet!)

```
Canvas canvas; // assuming you've initialized it, and drawn a lot of stuff already without saving.
GraphicsContent gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.translate(0, addedHeight);
```

After this call your new coordinates should also be transformed, meaning you either have to compensate when adding new data, or call save (which means things can't be modified after that (propably not what you want)).

**Edit**

Another way of accomplishing the same effect is by creating a new canvas everytime you need to expand in the negative direction. Multiple canvas instances can overlay eachother, and when the background is set to transparent the previous drawn lines will still be visible. (make sure to translate the previous canvas to compensate for the negative expansion!)

Comment: The translate method did not move the previously drawn line.

Comment: @Ember I added an alternative but as you posted yourself, for larger reaches you either need to scale/repaint. or only render the most recent part of your data.